# А как сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог изменять язык один раз?

Tags: python, telebot, бот

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

TOKEN = '...'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def startCommunicate(message):
    inline_keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    buttonRu = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = "Русский", callback_data = "button_ru")
    buttonUz = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = "Узбекский", callback_data = "button_uz")

    inline_keyboard.add(buttonRu, buttonUz)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выберите язык", reply_markup = inline_keyboard)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
    def handle_callback_query(call):
        if call.data == "button_ru":
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать!")
        else:
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Xush kelibsiz!")

bot.polling()
```

Выбираю язык русский, печатает на соответствующим языке, выбираю узбекский так что все норм, вот только я хочу чтобы после выбора языка чтобы не возможно было выбирать язык снова... Какую проверку написать подскажите пожалуйста... Делаю проверку но все равно это задача не решается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно записать ответ пользователя в базу данных и если запись уже есть, то выводить информацию на том языке, что в таблице. Только так